# Assign roles to identity from database

Tags: authorization, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm writing a blazor site that needs to allow access to certain pages based on records in a pre-existing SQL database. I've been researching what is required, but have mostly found instructions on doing this for .Net Core 1.0, but the process has changed for 2.0 and above, and I can't find a complete picture of what I need to do.

My site uses windows authentication. I've modified a page with this: @attribute [Authorize(Roles="Editor")]. I've added an IClaimsTransformation implementation as follows:

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation {

    private readonly Model model;

    public ClaimsTransformer(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal) {
        var cp = principal.Clone();
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity;
        var userName = identity.Name;
        var usec = await model.ApprovalUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Login, userName));
        if (usec != null) {
            if (usec.IsEditor) identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Editor"));
        }
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Model is an EF Core model. I've removed all but the Editor claim for the moment, to keep things simpler.

The following is my ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddDbContext<Model>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddBlazoredToast();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddAuthorization(opt => {
            opt.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
            opt.AddPolicy("Editor", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Editor"));
        });
    }
```

And this is my Configure:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

When I navigate to the page with the authorization attribute I get a "Not authorized" message, but my IClaimsTransformation implementation is never called. I'm not sure if I need to add something to ConfigureServices to register it with the authorization system (as well as registering it as a scoped service). I'm also not convinced that this is the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(opt => {
            opt.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
            opt.AddPolicy("Editor", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Editor"));
        });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems the answer was to have the following line in ConfigureServices:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Instead of simply

```
services.AddAuthentication();
```

I'd assumed that, since the application was aware of my windows credentials, authentication had successfully taken place, but I guess not.

Also the policy stuff wasn't needed - obviously with hindsight, as I'm using roles rather than policies. I guess I'd been trying so many permutations at that point, that I'd lost sight of what I was trying to achieve